# How do you translate duos to Spanish?

Tags: plurales

In English the plural of *duo* is *duos*. However, I am not sure in Spanish.

I looked in the DRAE that is the most famous dictionary in Spanish and I did not find the plural. Then, I am not sure if duos in Spanish is `dúo` or `dúos`.

Google and linguee.es translate *duos* to *dúos*.

I forgot to say that I believe that this is an important question because Wikipedia says "Los Dúo is a studio album released by Juan Gabriel on February 10, 2015."

Then, it seems that the company of the famous Mexican singer Juan Gabriel made a big mistake using for plural `dúo` instead of `dúos.`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That word has nothing special and its plural is formed using the common rules:
http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Iwao8PGQ8D6QkHPn4i

See these examples of usage (dúos):  http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categor%C3%ADa:D%C3%BAos_de_m%C3%BAsica
http://www.movistar.com.pe/internet/trios-y-duos/duos

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, Wikipedia and Movistar are not trusted sources for Spanish grammar.

Comment: You shouldn't need any special source. It a simple plural form constructed using the common rules. If a noun end on not accented vowel you put a 's' at the end.

Comment: What about cualquiera?

Comment: You have that information in the same RAE link I've provided in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the link of the RAE! That is the best source. I will study it and I will be back.

Answer (score 2):

The plural of [dúo](http://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%BAo) is dúos.

> Un dúo de guitarras.
>
> Varios dúos de guitarras.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, how can you prove your claim?

Comment: @Beginner, if you follow the link provided on the "dúo" word you'll see a es.wiktionary entry in which the singular and plural forms are explained.